# image not getting displayed after changing src attribute of img using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net-mvc-3, model-view-controller

I have an image on my page. On clicking a button I want to change the src of the image and display the new image. Below is my code.

```
<img id="img_change" src = "~/content/images/img1.jpg" />
```

Below i have

```
<script>
$("document").ready(function() {
  $("button").click(function() {
    $("#img_change").attr("src","~/content/images/img2.jpg");
  });
});
```

On clicking the image is not getting displayed. I've tried all that I know.

Comment: Your code works perfectly, can it be a problem in the url?

Comment: Your code is working fine, make sure that image exists in content folder. Is it there in images folder ?

Answer (score 0):

It's because your selector is not correct. Your code should be like this:

```
$("document").ready(function() {
  $("button").click(function() {
    // "#img_change" and not "img_change"
    $("#img_change").attr("src","~/content/images/img2.jpg");
  });
});
```

You need to have `#` in front of your selector since you are using an ID to target the correct element.

Comment: I'm sorry, that was a typo here. I had selected using #img_change like u commented. Still it's not getting displayed. Even the src changes to img2, but no image is displayed

Comment: Have you checked the console of your browser if any message is present to help us understand your problem? Why do you use path using the `~` ? Have you try your code with absolute URL to check ?

Comment: I tried using the absolute path like this..   $("#img_change").attr("src","C:/Users/Me/Documents/Visual Studio 203/Projects/Project1/Content/Images/img2.jpg");                                             Its not getting displayed, console says "Not allowed to load local resource". Ive specified Img1 path src using ~ and its getting displayed. Are there any restrictions on using ~ with attr() ?

Answer (score 0):

@Swatto Thnku so much. The browser console error was indicating that the path was not accessible.
I changed it to 
$("#img_change").attr("src","/Content/Images/img2.jpg");
and it is working now. 
Thnks again